# NFS ganesha + glusterfs only allows directory creating

Tags: nfs, glusterfs

I have sort of a weird issue with NFS ganesha and GlusterFS, where I am only able to create directories (`mkdir foo`), but trying to create files (`echo bar | tee baz`) failes with with `touch: cannot touch 'baz': No such file or directory

I have mounted with `mount -t nfs localhost:/gluster /mnt`. If i mount the Gluster directly with `mount -t glusterfs localhost:/gluster /mnt` everything works correct as far as I can tell.

My config for ganesha is

```
 # create new

NFS_CORE_PARAM {
    # possible to mount with NFSv3 to NFSv4 Pseudo path
    mount_path_pseudo = true;
    # NFS protocol
    Protocols = 3,4;
}
EXPORT_DEFAULTS {
    # default access mode
    Access_Type = RW;
}
EXPORT {
    # uniq ID
    Export_Id = 101;
    # mount path of Gluster Volume
    Path = "/mnt/data/gluster";
    FSAL {
        # any name
        name = GLUSTER;
        # hostname or IP address of this Node
        hostname="192.168.65.14";
        # Gluster volume name
        volume="gluster";
    }
    Disable_ACL = TRUE;
    # config for root Squash
    Squash="No_root_squash";
    # NFSv4 Pseudo path
    Pseudo="/gluster";
    # allowed security options
    SecType = "sys";
    Transports = "UDP","TCP" ;
    Protocols = "3","4" ;
}
LOG {
    # default log level
    Default_Log_Level = WARN;
}
```

And the OS is ubuntu in virtualbox (bento/ubunut-20.04 in vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue was caused further down, since i used a MergerFS mount as a brick. Switching to just use regular folders worked just fine